# Importing typescript enums into vue/browser context gives errors or requires dependencies

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, enums

I'm having an issue importing type definitions from a separate module while working in Vue.

Here's a rundown of the typedefs I'm trying to import:

```
import { Server, createServer } from "net";

export namespace Testable {
  export interface t {
    1: string,
    apple: boolean
  }

  export const enum b {
    butter,
    fly,
    moth
  }

  export class apple extends Server {

  }
}
```

**I can import the namespace `Testable`, and import/use the interface `t`, but if I try and use the enum `b`, i get errors in Vue/webpack**

```
TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
```

This is sample code, of course, but using the live code, which has a database class, Vue/webpack said I needed cldr, dns, and other package dependencies:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 21 errors                                                                                                                               2:00:58 PM

These dependencies were not found:

* cldr in ./node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize.js, ./node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js and 6 others
* cldr/event in ./node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize.js, ./node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js and 5 others
* cldr/supplemental in ./node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/relative-time.js, ./node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/plural.js and 3 others
* handlebars in ./node_modules/......
```

Again, I'm only trying to import the enum, not the nodejs class to use in the browser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Maybe I should structure my project a little differently, tips on that would be helpful as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module will be compiled to:

```
export var Testable;
(function (Testable) {
    class apple extends Server {
    }
    Testable.apple = apple;
})(Testable || (Testable = {}));
```

Namespace is represented as IIFE and results in side effect. This results in entire module being evaluated on import.

Additionally, there's no real need for TypeScript namespaces in ES6 because ES modules already act as namespaces.

Tree shaking may improve if namespaces aren't used. The module should be at least marked as side effect-free for Webpack. Webpack [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) heavily depends on how the application is built, unused `class apple extends Server ...` may still be evaluated. Notice that in this case [`usedExports` tree-shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#clarifying-tree-shaking-and-sideeffects) is not effective because it relies on a minifier which may be disabled in development.

It's preferable in this case to not rely on tree shaking and keep types in separate module, this allows to import them directly.

Comment: After posting my question and more research, I finally had to let go of namespacing. Thank you for adding more wisdom to my world!


I think I'll take some time to separate out my types from here on out, because it seems like the best option!